# Any PHP debugger, Chrome or Firefox extension, to know which session variable setting where?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Does anybody know how can I debug to check where my session variable is setting in the code. There are lots on included files too. I tried site wide search for that session variable but unable to find any clue where it is being set.
May be anybody know any chrome or firefox extension that tell which variable setting where in the code. Just like firebug for javascript, where we can use debugger to check all the above possibilities.

Comment: Session variables will only ever be set server-side, so no Chrome or Firefox extension is capable of testing what is happening in your PHP scripts.... first check I'd do would be a global search in your PHP code for references to `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer to your question is "Use a proper PHP debugger, like [xDebug](http://www.xdebug.org/). This will allow you to do lots of stuff, including examining variables at any given point in the program, stepping through line by line, etc. Combined with a good quality IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse, it's an amazingly powerful tool.

However, if you really want a browser plugin, you could try either [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) or [Chrome Logger](http://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger/).

Both of these will require you to put debugging code into your program that sends debug data to the browser, but the debug info appears in the dev tools, rather than messing up your rendered page output, so it's a lot cleaner to use than just using `echo` or `print_r`, etc to display the info.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` PHP variables are set server-side; you won't be able to access them in the browser **unless** you output them there.

I would suggest placing several `var_dump($_SESSION)` statements in your PHP code to debug what key/value pairs are living in the `session` as your script executes.

Answer (score 0):

At the point in your php script you wish to know what is stored do this:

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php debugger Like (XDebug or Zend Debuger) by adding watch command which will track all changes of that variable, you will need capable IDE for that though.